# Polygon to multiline object in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector

Is there a possibility to create a multiline object from polygon object contours in ArcMap?

I found that Edit toolbar allows to create polygons from other shapes, but I couldn't find anywhere an option to create linear object from polygon.

Comment: In Arcmap there is an advance level tool called Feature To Line, have a look at that?

Comment: I think it would be [Feature to Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-line.htm), then [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) by _ContourValue_ field. That should get you multipart polylines representing each contour interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Hornbydd:

> In ArcMap there is an advance level tool called [Feature To Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-line.htm)

which:

> Creates a feature class containing lines generated by converting
>   polygon boundaries to lines, or splitting line, polygon, or both
>   features at their intersections.